# Newrelic Android plugin running on non-newrelic project, causing crash

Tags: android, newrelic

The Newrelic Android plugin is being run on a project that has no references to Newrelic. I have another project open that does use Newrelic, and I'm using Android Studio 2.2, gradle in-process daemon, and the latest Gradle and build tools:

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'`

and

`compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'`

In my other project which *does* use Newrelic, I'm using

`classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.+"`

and

`apply plugin: 'newrelic'
compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.+'`

I can see the newrelic class re-write logs in the output, which should not happen

`[newrelic.info] [my.class.Name] replacing call to com/google/gson/Gson.fromJson(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; with com/newrelic/agent/android/instrumentation/GsonInstrumentation.fromJson(Lcom/google/gson/Gson;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; (with instance check)`

This then caused my apk to be built somehow missing several Activity classes, so crashes with:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.activity.home.LobbyActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.activity.home.LobbyActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my.package-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.package.activity.home.LobbyActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my.package-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1095)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3084)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my.package.activity.home.LobbyActivity
                                                                       at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:338)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
                                                                            ... 13 more
                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.activity.home.LobbyActivity
                                                                       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                            ... 12 more
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available`

This is the same problem as [Application crashes in onCreate due to newrelic exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933298/application-crashes-in-oncreate-due-to-newrelic-exception), but the solutions there don't work for me. Those answers are from 2 years ago and no longer relevant (I am using a much newer Gradle version and Newrelic version, I tried deleting the .gradle and gradle project folders).