# Android Studio - new relic exception is coming when running app first time on device

Tags: android

Every time getting this exception when creating new project and run the project.
I am not adding any new relic plugin still this exception is coming continuously.
Please help me out

---

> 05-18 16:08:12.646 19923-19923/app.demo.debug I/art: Rejecting re-init
>   on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: **Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/newrelic/agent/android/api/v2/TraceFieldInterface**; 05-18
>   16:08:12.646 19923-19923/app.demo.debug I/art: Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **Didn't find class
>   "com.newrelic.agent.android.api.v2.TraceFieldInterface" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/base.apk", zip
>   file** "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk",
>   zip file "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip
>   file "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/lib/x86,
>   05-18 16:08:12.686 19923-19923/app.demo.debug E/AndroidRuntime: Caused
>   by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity; ... 15 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity at
>   java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityJB; ... 15 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB at
>   java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb; ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb at
>   java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread; ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityGingerbread at
>   java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Landroid/support/v4/app/SupportActivity; ... 15 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.support.v4.app.SupportActivity at
>   java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:742) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:362) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/newrelic/agent/android/api/v2/TraceFieldInterface; ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.newrelic.agent.android.api.v2.TraceFieldInterface" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/app.demo.debug-1/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) ... 15 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Relic Class Not Found ... I don't even use new relic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226772/new-relic-class-not-found-i-dont-even-use-new-relic)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
gradlew --stop
gradlew cleanBuildCache
gradlew clean
```