# Android App Crash on start - Didn't find class com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.HttpInstrumentation

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, crash, dependencies

App was working fine 2 days ago. But running same code from Android Studio is crashing app on start. I've checked the old code as well but that's still crashing. Build created from same code couple of days ago is working fine. Is it some problem because of Android Studio? Or may be because of gradle dependencies. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Here is the crash log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
Lcom/newrelic/agent/android/instrumentation/HttpInstrumentation;
```

Crash details on new relic:

```
Didn't find class "com.newrelic.agent.android.instrumentation.HttpInstrumentation"
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fixdconsumer-1/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fixdconsumer-1/lib/arm, 
/data/app/com.fixdconsumer-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Already tried these solutions but didn't work:
[New Relic Class Not Found ... I don't even use new relic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226772/new-relic-class-not-found-i-dont-even-use-new-relic)
https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/issues/387
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-blur/issues/110

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex try this it may help you

Comment: @akshay I've already added multidex, but it still crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic has since released `5.20.0` which fixes this `5.19.1` issue

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/mobile-release-notes/android-release-notes

Answer (score 1):

New relic has released `5.19.1` recently on September 10, 2018. This release is only needed by apps that target SDK 28 or higher. Mine targetSDK is 27. Due to higher version of new relic app crashed. So I have changed it to `5.19.0` and its solved now.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/mobile-release-notes/android-release-notes

Earlier:
implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.+'

Updated to:
implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.19.0'